# How to make the HTTP connection timeout/disconnected after a time interval?

Tags: java, http, connection, httpclient

I am new in Apache `HttpClient`, I used the following code to get the HTTP connection timeout (disconnected) after certain time interval:

```
PostMethod method = new PostMethod(authURL);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpClientParams params= new HttpClientParams();
params.setParameter(params.CONNECTION_MANAGER_TIMEOUT, 10); //10 Nano second
client.executeMethod(method);
```

but it wait for more than one minute without any hope to timeout/disconnect? Where can the problem be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 timeouts involved in HTTPClient, try to set both,

```
  client.getHttpConnectionManager().
        getParams().setConnectionTimeout(5000);
  client.getHttpConnectionManager().
        getParams().setSoTimeout(5000);
```

However, the values will be ignored if the connection is stuck in a native socket call. So you might have to run the request in a different thread so you can time it out. See my answer to this question on how to do that,

[java native Process timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247390/java-native-process-timeout/1249984#1249984)

Answer (score 1):

The connection manager timeout triggers when the act of trying to get a connection from your connection manager takes too long.  This is not the same as the timeout for the http connection itself.  Use HttpClientParams.setSoTimeout() instead.

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/params/HttpMethodParams.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29

Comment: thanks for your reply,,, 
I have tried the  HttpClientParams.setSoTimeout() but the problem still there,ny more suggestions,,,,

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at setting [SO_TIMEOUT](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/params/HttpMethodParams.html#SO_TIMEOUT) ?

> Sets the socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
>   in milliseconds to be used when
>   executing the method. A timeout value
>   of zero is interpreted as an infinite
>   timeout.