# If you discard a reference to a Future, will it still run?

Tags: java, future

In my method, I have to call another method (`AnotherMethod`) that returns a future.

eg.

```
private static void myMethod() {
    Future<MyObj> mjObj = AnotherMethod();
    return;
}
```

I don't actually care about the value returned by `AnotherMethod` (eg. the value of `myObj`), but I do want `AnotherMethod` to run fully.

If I discard the reference to the future (as in the above example), will `AnotherMethod` still finish running?

I understand it won't finish before returning from `myMethod`, but will it still complete at some point even though there's no reference to `myObj` anymore?

Comment: There is no guarantee that a future will ever run. But if you create it, say, via an executor, then the executor still has a reference to it.

Comment: Really depends on what `AnotherMethod()` does, simply creating a Future does not run it (as in `new Future()` - that's just a boring Object). If that method on the other hand sends some task to an `Executor` then it's referenced by the task queue and eventually executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Concurrency: Is cancelling Futures necessary for them to be Garbage Collected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20135304/java-concurrency-is-cancelling-futures-necessary-for-them-to-be-garbage-collect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, AnotherMethod always will be performed from the start to the end because you call it. As for concurrency, if AnotherMethod starts a Thread or submits task to an executor then this concurrent execution will not be interrupted. Garbage collector does not interrupt threads because they are GC roots - top level objects in JVM.