# Program stuck on an URL, cant move forward and won't time out

Tags: java, url, timeout

My program is a web crawler and its been stuck on a URL that apparently corresponds to a random Chinese site.  For some reason its not throwing an exception and the connection is not timing out.  I would have thought that these lines would prevent that.

```
static URLConnection in;
in = curURL.openConnection();
in.setConnectTimeout(2000);
pageSource = new StreamedSource(in);
```

I'm nearly positive this is the issue, any checks on the heap dump for memory leaks turned up nothing.

Comment: If it is risky url, I would suggest remove it.

Comment: Done.  Any attempts to visit the url either by curl or browser got me nothing anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setConnectTimeout()` only controls the timeout for establishing the connection. Once it has been started, it can last for a long time (basically until the server closes it). For instance you might be downloading a very large file over a slow link.

One solution would be to add a watchdog thread monitoring the connections and closing those which exceed some time limit.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I need, how should I go about doing that?

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party crawler library? If not you might want to look into existing solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026978/open-source-java-web-crawler

Comment: I'm using Jericho html parser, its nice for extracting information from a page but I don't see anything that would help me here.  Is there a way to put a time limit on the execution of a step in a loop?

Comment: The job of the crawler is (among other things) to queue, monitor and execute the requests, then it may pass the data to a parser. If you want to keep your code have a look at the accepted answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758612/executorservice-that-interrupts-tasks-after-a-timeout

Comment: So it turns out URLConnection has a setReadTimeout method that I failed to notice, I think my problems are solved.

Comment: I missed that one! Much better indeed!