# Set a timeout in Executor.execute()

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I need to execute tasks sequentially:

```java
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public void push(Runnable task) {
   executor.execute(task);
}
```

Sometimes a task never ends. I would like to set a timeout to prevent it from blocking the next.

*Edit*: I need a "*fire and forget*" design as I can't block the caller of this execution

Comment: Take a look at [ExecutorService that interrupts tasks after a timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758612/executorservice-that-interrupts-tasks-after-a-timeout)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using Future object.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do your task
        }
    };

    Future<?> future = executor.submit(task);

    future.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // awaits termination
```