# Spring, response within certain timeframe/timeperiod

Tags: spring, executorservice, spring-ws

I'd like for my endpoint to respond to a request within certain timeframe/timeperiod. For instance, the endpoint should respond to the request within 3 seconds, otherwise return an empty message or throw an exception.

Therefore I'm trying to find the right bells and whistles to use. I assume this can be done with the use of executors (ScheduledExecutor or similar), but I'm not sure if this is the right or preferred approach to go with. If one were to use this, would there be any consequences that I should be aware of? Or is there a way to do this using some sort of 'Spring' way?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Just write an if statement in the controller that checks the time and if you're outside of the timeframe - return 404 or error.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but seems like my question was a bit too vague. I edited the question to clarify what I meant and sorry for this.

Comment: I think Executor should work fine!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456313/simple-timeout-in-java