# Make a thread generate fixed number of requests per second

Tags: java, multithreading

I am doing calculations in milliseconds and I really do not want my thread to spend more time doing time calculations rather the job it is assigned to do. However I want to implement something that:

`1- It should not generate more than n requests per second`

`2- If it has generated less, it should start at zero for the next second(obviously :D)`

I am trying to do some performance benchmarking where my goal is to give all cpu to only processing and not time computations after every request. Roughly, I am processing

`08:36 - 171299 
08:37 - 170970 
08:38 - 163763`
 
I want to make sure I do not make more than `160000` requests per minute here. How to acheive that is the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your machine (even if it is a GameBoy) can easily handle one calculation à la `1000 / n` per second.

Comment: You should really post some code, it's not clear what you're trying to do and how you're trying to do it. It sounds like you want to use a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: @mumpitz I don't know what you've meant, I wouldn't call that helpful...

Comment: You should take a look at Guava's RateLimiter and search for examples on how to use it.

Comment: @FilipMalczak Thank you for your criticism, although it is in turn not very helpful. Despite my humorous wording, I actually tried to make a point: I don't think the calculation of the delays needed are a big problem. Your (honestly helpful) answer to this question does include the same calculation behind the scenes - which is fine, i think. It's a good way to deal with this anyway. Friends?

Comment: What happens with requests that span the second divider line? Or indeed, what is your original problem? Sounds to me like you've come up with a solution for a problem and now you're asking us to make your solution work rather than address the original problem. In essence this sounds like  an X-Y problem.

Comment: There are two parts, design and implementing. I am looking for all possible designs. I can implement it later. I still do not have the design in place to make this work. If I create threads on the fly with 1 sec timeout, I shall be spending lot of time in creation of threads.

Comment: @AnimeshJain I'm afraid that without you describing the problem you're trying to solve it's unlikely that you will get any useful answers.

Comment: I am trying to do some performance benchmarking where my goal is to give all cpu to only processing and not time computations after every request. Roughly, I am processing

  TIME - No Of Requests 
08:36 - 171299
08:37 - 170970
08:38 - 163763

I want to make sure I do not make more than 160000 requests per minute here. How to acheive that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to run some code every second and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456313/simple-timeout-in-java) to set timeout on that code. In the end, your runnable that should have 1-second timeout should generate up to `n` requests, and if it times out, it will start in next second with new context.

Comment: Yes, that is a idea I had. I am looking for ways if I can use the same threadpool every time. Can I do that? or I need to timeout the thread every second and create a new one always ?

Comment: ScheduledExecutorService is still an ExecutorService - I think you can use the same pool to schedule the piece of code that you'll wrap in timeout  and the real task itself. I am not sure of that though and I guess it may lead to some problems. Worst case scenario - keep two pools - one for scheduling, the other one for doing "real" work.