# abandon execution of a method after 3 seconds

Tags: java, java-8, timeout

I've this method:

```
public ResponseDTO getManh(QueryDTO manhQueryDTO) {
  return requestHttpService.post(ManhQueryResponseDTO.class,
                    uri(properties.getManhattan().getUrl(), REQUEST_QUERY), manhQueryDTO);
}
```

I need abandon execution of a method after 3 seconds.

does anyone have any idea what to do?

Comment: Are you looking for a timeout? If so, does this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19456313/4616087) help?

Comment: I will try... you help so much! tks

Comment: There is no information available on how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple timeout in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456313/simple-timeout-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I create a object only to control this call - tryTimeout().

```
    ResponseDTO responseDTO = tryTimeout();
```

this is the control obj:

```
  private ResponseDTO tryTimeout() {

    final Duration timeout = Duration.ofSeconds(1);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    final Future<ResponseDTO> handler = executor.submit(new Callable() {
        @Override
        public ResponseDTO call() throws Exception {
            return origin.serviceToCall();
        }
    });

    try {
        return handler.get(timeout.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        LOGGER.error("TIMEOUT");

    } finally {
        executor.shutdown();
    }

}
```