# How to force java to move on to the next line of code if it takes too long to run the current line?

Tags: java, time

I have a line of code that might take too long to run(sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't), and I would like to move on to the next line of code if this happens. Is there any way in Java that I can do this?

Comment: Did you consider the possibility of running that in a separate thread?

Comment: `I would like to move on to the next line of code if this happens` did you mean to interrupt that line if it takes too long?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Yes, that's what I meant. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple timeout in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456313/simple-timeout-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can record the start time mills,and you say it might take too long to run. So I just consider it as a loop. If so,you just need to get the end time miils , check the difference between the start time mills and the end time miils, if it is too large, just call break.

Comment: `I just consider it as a loop` This is not necessarily true as OP wrote `code that might take too long to run(sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't)` probably he isn't talking about loops.

Comment: Then just put it into a thread, wait while the thread is alive,if it takes too long, break and do other tasks. You can also keep the thread running.

Comment: @XuanXu Thank you, could you provide example code of how to kill a thread if it takes too long?

Comment: It is unsafe to kill the thread if it is still running. But you can call thread.interrupt(), if the thread is in blocked state, it will throw an interrupt exception and exit. And if you don't mind, you can call stop () function to destroy it.