# How to wait for 2 minutes for method to complete, but then Exit and continue?

Tags: java, threadpool, delay

How to wait for 2 minutes for method to complete, but if it does not complete then Exit and continue?

I want to wait for 2 minutes for method to complete, but if it does not complete in 2 minutes then Exit execution and continue ahead.

Comment: can u please add some code?

Comment: Post your attempts/thoughts please.

Comment: use `join(2000);` in the thread which wants to wait.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What do you mean by exit? Do you want to continue your execution without the answer, or do you also want to stop executing whatever should have produced the answer? (The latter can not be done safely in a generic way).

Comment: @G.S  An MCVE is far more useful than 'some code'. See link in my first comment for a run-down of why that is so.

Comment: You will have to create a different thread to check the time.

Comment: @Roger - I want to continue the execution without answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of Executor and Futures I think this could help

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    Future<String> future = executor.submit( new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return someVeryLengthMethod();
        }});

    String result = null;
    try {
        result = future.get(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Somebody interrupted us
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // Something went wring, handle it...
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        // Too long time
        future.cancel(true);
    }
    // Continue with what we have...
```

This will wait for the answer a specified time, and if the result is not available within that time the future is cancelled (which may or may not actually stop the execution of that task), and the code can continue.

Answer (score 6):

Using the jcabi API has been pretty helpful for this kind of thing: [jcabi API](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/annotation-timeable.html)

Pretty slick annotation based API, so in your case it would work like this:

```
@Timeable(limit = 120, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public void methodYouWantToTime(){...}
```

Answer (score 4):

A combination of the following might work:

Time tracking:

```
// use this to record when a process started
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
// subsequent calls can be used to track how long something has been running?
long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
```

Separate process:

```
java.lang.Thread // Extend this class
// And implement your own run() method.
```

In the loop that waits for the separate thread to finish, you could use:

```
Thread.interrupt(); // This method could then be used to stop the execution
Thread.stop(); // This is also another way to stop execution, but it is deprecated and its use is frowned upon!
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

This question is explained in different threads. The best way is to use an ThreadPool with a timeout (see [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)).

Example, submit a task and wait 60 seconds for the answer:

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Future<Object> future = pool.submit(new Callable<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            return this;
        }
    });
    Object result = future.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If you want to wait for the completion of a task but you are not expecting any output, better use:

```
pool.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    // Wait until the task is completed, then shut down the pool
    pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

More details in this thread: [ExecutorService that interrupts tasks after a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758612/executorservice-that-interrupts-tasks-after-a-timeout)