# ScheduledExecutorService and ThreadPoolTaskExecutor that interrupts tasks after a timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

I Used ExecutorService that interrupts tasks after a timeout.I use a ScheduledExecutorService for this. First I submitted the thread and it once to begin immediately and retain the future that is created. After that i use ScheduledExecutorService as a new task that would cancel the retained future after some period of time.

```html
//Start Spring executor to submit tasks
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("taskExecutor"); 

CompletionService completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService(taskExecutor);
//End Spring executor to submit tasks

// Start ScheduledExecutorService  to submit returned future object to timeout

ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty("DBPOLLER_COREPOOLSIZE")));

final Future<String> future = completionService.submit(batchJob); // Submit actual task and get future

// submit future

executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
                         future.cancel(true);
      }
   }, dbPollerTimeOut, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

int count = taskExecutor.getActiveCount();

 if (count == 0) {

                taskExecutor.shutdown();
                executor.shutdown();
                finalExitStatus = 0;                    
                break;

            }
```

I have implemented the solution which is in below url:
[ExecutorService that interrupts tasks after a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758612/executorservice-that-interrupts-tasks-after-a-timeout), it was working fine, until timeout, but once timeout happens, it cancels all the`enter code here` tasks i ThreadPool which is not acceptable. I need to cancel only tasks that are long running and reach timeout.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: What is `batchJob`? Cancelling it must be responsible for cancelling "all the `enter code here` tasks [in] ThreadPool." So, show the code for `batchJob`. Does `batchJob` somehow reference a lot of other tasks? That would be a problem.

Comment: See [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946627/scheduledexecutorservice-that-interrupts-after-a-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what your `CompletionService` is, and you are submitting your `batchJob` on it, so it is hard to tell exact root cause of your problem. But ideal scenario of submitting few tasks and cancelling them after some time, is to use `ScheduledExecutorService` for both purposes.

So, can try submitting the `batchJob`on instance of `ScheduledExecutorService` i.e. `executor`.

```
final Future<String> future = executor.submit(batchJob); // Submit actual task and get future
```

**EDIT UPDATE:** **Important change you SHOULD do in your code**
I see that you are never stopping your `ScheduledExecutorService` which is wrong because resources it occupies will never be released until you stop it. So, your updated code should be as below:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty("DBPOLLER_COREPOOLSIZE")));
final Future<String> future = executor.submit(batchJob); // Submit actual task and get future
executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        future.cancel(true);
        executor.shutdownNow();
      }
   }, dbPollerTimeOut, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```