# Java 8 CompletableFuture , Stream and Timeouts

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, java-stream, completable-future

i'm trying to process some amount of data concurrently using `CompletableFuture` and `Stream`
So far i have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    System.out.println("start");

    List<String> collect = Stream.of("1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
            "6", "7")
            .map(x -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(getStringSupplier(x)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("stop out!");
}


public static Supplier<String> getStringSupplier(String text) {
    return () -> {

        System.out.println("start " + text);
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("stop " + text);
        return "asd" + text;
    };
}
```

And output is fine :

`start
start 1
start 4
start 3
start 2
start 5
start 6
start 7
stop 4
stop 1
stop 5
stop 2
stop 6
stop 3
stop 7
stop out!`

However right now i want to add timeout to that job. Lets say it should be canceled after 1 SECOND. And return null or some other value to `collect` list. (I would prefer some value indicating cause).

How can i achieve that ?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: In Java 9 you can do this easily with `CompletableFuture#completeOnTimeout` (http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completeOnTimeout-T-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)

Comment: So far (and probably will be for a while) my company works with java 8 so i can not use that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the way of doing that:

```
 private static final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(
                1,
                new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
                        .setDaemon(true)
                        .setNameFormat("failAfter-%d")
                        .build());

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    System.out.println("start");
    final CompletableFuture<Object> oneSecondTimeout = failAfter(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .exceptionally(xxx -> "timeout exception");
    List<Object> collect = Stream.of("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
            .map(x -> CompletableFuture.anyOf(createTaskSupplier(x)
                    , oneSecondTimeout))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("stop out!");
    System.out.println(collect);
}

public static CompletableFuture<String> createTaskSupplier(String x) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(getStringSupplier(x))
            .exceptionally(xx -> "PROCESSING ERROR : " + xx.getMessage());
}


public static Supplier<String> getStringSupplier(String text) {
    return () -> {

        System.out.println("start " + text);
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (text.equals("1")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("LOGIC ERROR");
        }
        try {
            if (text.equals("7"))
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("stop " + text);
        return "result " + text;
    };
}

public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> failAfter(Duration duration) {
    final CompletableFuture<T> promise = new CompletableFuture<>();
    scheduler.schedule(() -> {
        final TimeoutException ex = new TimeoutException("Timeout after " + duration);
        return promise.completeExceptionally(ex);
    }, duration.toMillis(), MILLISECONDS);
    return promise;
}
```

It returns :

```
 start
 start 1
 start 3
 start 4
 start 2
 start 5
 start 6
 start 7
 stop 6
 stop 4
 stop 3
 stop 5
 stop 2
 stop out!
 [PROCESSING ERROR : java.lang.RuntimeException: LOGIC ERROR, result 2, result 3, result 4, result 5, result 6, timeout exception]`
```

What do you think about that, can you spot any flaws of that solution ?

Answer (score 3):

For others, who are not limited with Java 8, you can use [completeOnTimeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completeOnTimeout-T-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method, which was introduced in Java 9.

```
List<String> collect = Stream.of("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
        .map(x -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(getStringSupplier(x))
                .completeOnTimeout(null , 1, SECONDS))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(toList())
        .stream()
        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
        .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the job in another CompletableFuture and it would give out a TimeoutException if the given time is exceeded. You can separate the TimeoutException catch block if you want to handle it specially.

```
    List<String> collect = null;
    try {
        collect = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
                Stream.of("1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
                        "6", "7")
                        .map(x -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(getStringSupplier(x)))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                        .stream()
                        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ).get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //separate out the TimeoutException if you want to handle it differently 

    }

    System.out.println(collect); //would be null in case of any exception
```

Comment: Problem with that sollution is that if exception occurs `collect` List is `null` so i am loosing data from sucessfull executions and i cant let it happend

Answer (score 0):

you can try CompletableFuture's overloaded supplyAsync method with executor parameter ***(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(getStringSupplier(x), timeoutExecutorService))*** and can refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758612/executorservice-that-interrupts-tasks-after-a-timeout) for timeoutExecutorService.

Comment: You are right that could work. But that sollution uses `Feature` instead on `CompletableFuture`. I would prefer to use `CompletableFuture` object because i want to learn new stuff.