# Is there anyway to have a thread to catch InterruptException besides putting a Time.Unit.Seconds.sleep?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a thread, inside its making a database call that sometimes hangs, normally timeout should be handle in the client library, but in this case the client library doesn't handle it correctly so I have to add an extra scheduled job to cancel the thread that is making db call if it takes too long to avoid back pressure.

Right now I am terminating the thread through

```
final Future handler = executor.submit(new MyTask());

executor2.schedule(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                handler.cancel(true);
            }
}, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Is there a proper way to interrupt a thread without `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);` ? Adding sleep seems hacky

```
    @Override
    public Boolean call() {
        try  {
            // Sometimes hangs
            db.call();
            // Need it to be here to call InterruptedException
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
            return true;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758612/executorservice-that-interrupts-tasks-after-a-timeout

Comment: You definitely don't need to sleep to check if a thread was interrupted. Just `return Thread.currentThread().interrupted();`. (The sleep doesn't run until the db call returns anyway, so this sleep doesn't help your db call finish earlier).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a proper way to interrupt a thread without `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);` ?

This doesn't interrupt a thread. It merely checks if the thread has been interrupted, either before or during the sleep, and throws an `InterruptedException` if it was.

If you want to interrupt a thread, use:

```
t.interrupt();
```

If you want to check if the current thread has been interrupted, use:

```
Thread.interrupted()
```

Note that this clears this interrupted state: use `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` to check without clearing the state.

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 9, you can use [CompletableFuture.orTimeout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#orTimeout%28long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29):

```
Future<?> handler = CompletableFuture.runAsync(new MyTask())
    .orTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```