# How to perform several tasks synchronously with timeout and cancelation of tasks without continuation of tasks

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using the *Spring Framework* and Java 11. Does there exist a mechanism to perform several async tasks (like @Async spring)?
But with cancelation of all tasks on timeout without killing/interrupting threads? I mean something like go-routine context cancelation in go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend you read about: ExecutorService, ScheduledExecutorService and SimplAsyncTaskExecutor to understand the mechanism of task executor.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html

It provide few built-in functions to execute the task asych with timeout and cancel policy...

You can refer the answer here how to execute schedule with timeout:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759040/1439560