# kill a java thread after a certain period of time

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm having a java code which i would have to kill because sometimes it takes 100% cpu usage for infinite time. Below is the code but java has no means to kill this thread while running.

If this is possible in any other programming language like scala or groovy which i can addon to the present java project or altogether i have to shift to some other programming language please suggest.

```
p = Pattern.compile("(?i).*\\bc\\+\\+\\B.*");
m = p.matcher(desc);
if(m.find()) {
      desc = desc + "cplusplus ";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something similar to that? https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2018/05/31/java-threadpoolexecutor-with-automatic-task-cancellation-after-timeout/

Comment: Executors are not able to kill without any explicit code to interrupt or sleep

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ExecutorService that interrupts tasks after a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758612/executorservice-that-interrupts-tasks-after-a-timeout)

Comment: no Executor only kills when there's a sleep or interrupt in the code