# How can i make a Java Daemon

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I need to do a periodic operation (call a java method) in my web app (jsp on tomcat).
How can i do this ? Java daemon or others solutions ?

Comment: similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053936/how-to-execute-task-for-a-specific-period-in-java/3053971#3053971

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) for periodic execution of a task.  However, if you require more complex cron-like scheduling then take a look at [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/).  In particular I'd recommend using [Quartz in conjunction with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz) if you go down this route, as it provides a nicer API and allows you to control your job firing in configuration.

**ScheduledExecutorService Example (taken from Javadoc)**

```
 import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
 class BeeperControl {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
       Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void beepForAnHour() {
        final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
                public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
            };
        final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
        scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
            }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
    }
 }
```

Comment: My operation don't have an end time.
I need to do this, for example, every week.
How can i do this ?

Comment: If you are using ScheduledExecutorService you need to use scheduleWithFixedDelay or scheduleAtFixedRate.  For tasks running once per week or at certain times of the month I tend to favour Quartz, as you can provide a simply cron expression in config describing the exact times the job should run.

Answer (score 4):

Adams answer is right on the money.   If you do end up rolling your own (rather than going the quartz route), you'll want to kick things off in a [ServletContextListener](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).  Here's an example, using java.util.Timer, which is more or less a dumb version of the ScheduledExexutorPool.

```
public class TimerTaskServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener
{
   private Timer timer;

   public void contextDestroyed( ServletContextEvent sce )
   {
      if (timer != null) {
         timer.cancel();
      }
   }

   public void contextInitialized( ServletContextEvent sce )
   {
      Timer timer = new Timer();
       TimerTask myTask = new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run()
         {
            System.out.println("I'm doing awesome stuff right now.");
         }
      };

      long delay = 0;
      long period = 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds;
      timer.schedule( myTask, delay, period );
  }

}
```

And then this goes in your web.xml

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>com.TimerTaskServletContextListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

Just more food for thought!