# How to make a Task complete with in 1 minute or discard it if it doesn't complete

Tags: java

I am working on a Java EE Based application, where I need to PDF reports using itext API.
Basically my requirement is that, if the report generation takes more than 1 minute then stop it.

So for this I am implementing this business requirement in this way

```
Thread t = new Thread(myPojoclass); 

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long endTime = startTime + 60000;

t.start();

while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) 
{

}

t.interrupt();  // Tell the thread to stop
```

And inside my `myPojoclass` as mentioned above, this is a Thread which implements `Runnable` interface and inside its run method it is consisting of connecting to Database 
and getting the results and giving it to an `ArrayList`

Please let me know if this is correct ??

Comment: These posts has answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2758612/948268  and  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1247390/948268

Answer (score 2):

there is a good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread). Since your thread is connecting to a database I strongly recommend (if you haven't done it already) to catch the `InterruptException` exception and within its block close your connection and rollback if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you can use executor service

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2); 
 final Future handler = executor.submit(new Callable(){ ... });
 executor.schedule(new Runnable(){
     public void run(){
         handler.cancel();
     }      
 }, 60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

more details 
[ExecutorService that interrupts tasks after a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758612/executorservice-that-interrupts-tasks-after-a-timeout)

Comment: You should also mention that you copied it from this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/2758612/948268